# Smooth vertical scrolling - Block user-scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I've made a page with smooth vertical scrolling, and I was wondering if you can somehow "block" so the user can't use his mouse or touchpad to scroll on the page - when they do that the whole idea kinda stops.

you can see the scrolling on my webpage.
[enter link description here](http://www.sabinequardon.dk)

So far I've just hidden the scrollbar so they can't do it.
I guess you can say what I'm asking for is, can you "block" manually scrolling?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The way you've done it is fine.  I don't think you can cancel a scroll event, like you can with other event (keypress, button clicks etc..)

Setting overflow to hidden would be how I'd do it as well, as that completely stops all scrolling.  The event doesn't even take place in the background.

The following code will block scrolling with the mousewheel.  While this isn't relevant for me as I can't use the mousewheel to scroll anyway, it may block scrolling with your touchpad.

Just add this to one of your included js files...

```
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = function(event){
    if (event.preventDefault) event.preventDefault();
    event.returnValue = false;
}
```

Here's an example...

http://jsfiddle.net/johncmolyneux/aSw2g/

Comment: It's just annoying that when i suddenly scroll on my touchpad instead of clicking on the links. could be nice if the user actually HAD to click on the link to scroll.

Comment: Okay - I've not experience that problem as I'm on a desktop, not a laptop.  Scrolling is totally disabled for a desktop - scroll wheel, cursor keys, page up/down all disabled.

Comment: I realized that i've set the hide overflow to overflowY instead of just overflow, and it worked! :)

Answer (score 0):

they are several solutions, but there's none that I found perfect. The simpliest is:

- set the css property "overflow" to hidden (if on your body, you must set height and width to 100% on body and html, plus no margins/padding borders).
- also you can add a listenner to scroll events, then prevent them with event.prevendDefault().

But they are always undesirable effects that can "scroll" pages(and blocks) without a mousescroll:

- first is selection: your layout break here. To try it, select from the upper and go down, then the page will scroll(with chrome). this is unlikely to happen when there is no text and no drag and drops, but once it happens your users are lost since there is no scrollbars.
- second is `scrollIntoView()`. You can call that via javascript, or the browser will do it automatically sometimes ( href to an anchor, input focus, "scroll memory at reload" ). This is were there is most risks, but there is very few control over these.

finally, one "bad" solution I found is to regularly force scrollTop property of elements to 0. But most probably you won't have to get there and the CSS `body { overflow: hidden; height: 100% }` will be sufficient.